# &rhs != this, compare a reference to a pointer?

Tags: c++, g++, operator-overloading, pass-by-reference

this is an assignment operator. `&rhs != this` is confusing. my questions: rhs is a reference of Message type. What does `&rhs` mean? what does `&` do (a memory address of a reference?)?
Another question is about `return *this` . since we want a reference to type Message, but *this is a Message typed object, right? How can we return an object to a reference?

```
Message& Message::operator=(const Message &rhs)
{
    if (&rhs != this)
    {
         some functions;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: to understand WHY this PATTERN is common in most any operator= method, read Scott Meyer's Effective C++; in the 3rd edition, see items #10 and #11 (those are readable via amazon's "Look Inside" mechanism) http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Specific-Improve-Programs-Designs/dp/0321334876#reader_0321334876  Actually, the entire book is recommended reading.

Comment: @franji1: I wouldn't call it common. It is even better if you go swap all the way, then you usually do not need to force the self-assignment-check onto each and every caller.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`&rhs` means address of the object which reference is referecing to.

```
Message a;
const Message &rhs = a;

if (&rhs == &a) std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
```

This is will print `true`.

A reference is not a different object; it is just a syntactic sugar of pointer, which points to the same object whose reference it is. So when you write `return this`, it returns a pointer to the object, but if you write `return *this`, it returns either a *copy* of the object, or *reference* to the object, depending on the return type. If the return type is `Message &`,  then you tell the compiler that "*don't make a copy and instead return the **same** object*". Now the *same* object is nothing but a reference. A reference of an object can be made anytime. For example, see the declaration of `rhs` above; it is `const Message & rhs = a`, since the targer type is mentioned as reference type, you're making a reference `rhs` of the object `a`. It is that simple.

Comment: what about the `return *this`? `*this` is an object. but the return type is a Message typed reference `Message&`

Comment: so basically, rhs is just another name for a.

Comment: @ihm: Yes. It just yet another name. It is an alias.

Comment: @ihm: 'this' is a pointer. You can dereference pointers to get their value, like *pointer. Doing *this returns the value of the pointer, which is converted into a reference since the function returns a reference. It's for allowing functions to be chained. (A = B) + C; (Assigns 'B' to 'A' and adds 5 to C. Function chaining can be abused to make messy code, but it can also be used well to create clean code. std::cout and the standard stream classes using function chaining with the bitshift operators << >> to chain text output: std::cout << "Blah" << "blah"; Where each << is a call to operator<<.

Answer (score 4):

Besides [Nawaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415784/nawaz)'s great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191628/rhs-this-compare-a-reference-to-a-pointer/8191633#8191633), I want to point out that you have to be careful about returning a reference to a local variable which will go out of scope after function return. So avoid returning a reference like this:

```
string& foo()
{
    string result = "abc";
    return result;
}
```

which causes the following compiler warning:

> reference to local variable `result` returned

Answer (score 2):

A reference is just an *alias* to an object. References are formed by request of the function that is called; they are not (necessarily) part of an object's type. This is probably already familiar to you, but consider this:

```
void f1(int a) { ++a; }
void f2(int & a { ++a; }

int main()
{
  int x = 5;
  f1(x); 
  f2(x);
}
```

Surely you know the difference between the two functions. But note that `x` is always just an object of type `int`. Whether it is passed by reference or by value is not a property of `x`, but rather of the function.

The same goes for return types:

```
int q;
int g1()   { return q; }
int & g2() { return q; }

int main()
{
  ++g2();
  ++g1(); // error
}
```

Again, `q` is just an object. Whether `return q;` returns it by value or by reference is not a property of `q`, but of the function. `g1` makes a copy of `q`, while `g2` returns a reference to the actual `q` object (which we can increment). (The return value of `g1` cannot be incremented, precisely because it doesn't have a permanent existence and this would be meaningless (technially, the expression is an rvalue).)

So in you example, `return *this;` returns a *reference* to the object itself. That has nothing to do with `this`, but it has everything to do with the fact that the return type of the function is `Message&`.

Comment: Are you implying that `++g1()` is a compilation error *because it returns an rvalue*? If so, it is not entirely correct.

Comment: @Nawaz: No, the expression *is* an rvalue at that point, and since it's of fundamental type, it cannot be incremented. I've reworded it.